# Python redis get method raises an AttributeError for non existing key

Tags: python, redis

I have the following part of code:

`rd = redis.Redis(host, port, db, password, socket_timeout,
            connection_pool, charset, errors, unix_socket_path)`

`check_flag = rd.get("some_key")
 if check_flag is not None:
    do_something()`

But `get` method of Redis raises an AttributeError:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

I'm not sure if it's OK to share full text of traceback here.

I'm using redis 2.10.5

Do somebody have any ideas what is going on?

P.S. I was looking through stackoverflow for the same issues, but with no success

UPD: Added full traceback

`init_flag = self.redis.get("face_init")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 880, in get
    return self.execute_command('GET', name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 572, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 475, in _connect
    for k, v in iteritems(self.socket_keepalive_options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis/_compat.py", line 27, in iteritems
    return x.iteritems()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: I guess a complete traceback would be useful. Somewhere there is a string where there should be a dict I guess.

Comment: @siwica, updated question with full trace

Comment: Did you set any values previously and the connection is alive?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I didn't set any values, but according to documentation it must return None, but not raise an error. Yeah, you're right: I'm trying to set value via Python, the same problem...

Comment: The problem seems to be that somewhere a string is passed as the argument to the `socket_keepalive_options` option of the `Connection` constructor when a dict is actually expected. Did you manually specify a value for `socket_keepalive_options` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have found a bug in the redis-py library.

I'd first try updating to the newest version of the library, as well as trying out other releases, and see if you see any different behaviour. You should be able to checkout any given release of it from here, https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py, and then use the command listed [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/INSTALL) to do a local install of the checked out code.

You might also want to try under a few different network conditions. That code path in the trace looks like it's related to sending the packets to the Redis Server, so it might be worth testing what happens when you're not connecting to a valid server address.

You could also run the Redis [Monitor](http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) command from the redis cli, to see if anything is making it to the server or not.

If you still don't see any thing obviously wrong with those additional bits of trouble shooting, I'd open up an issue on the Redis-py github repo, and see if they can help track down the underlying issue.

Comment: The issue was stupid: I found an example of using redis with `errors = 'strict'` and this parameter raises this error ;(

Comment: That's weird. Looking at the Redis source that should actually not cause the issue, as `errors='strict'` only overwrites `encoding_errors` which default value is `'strict'` anyways. This should only yield a `DeprecationWarning` but nothing more...